# Laravel 6 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException Conexión rechazada

Tags: base-de-datos, laravel-6

No doy en la tecla, probé varias indicaciones y el error persiste. No puedo hacer que se concrete la migración:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lara6c and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites_Laravel/lara6/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites_Laravel/lara6/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=lara6c", "root", "", [])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites_Laravel/lara6/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: ¿Has probado reinstalando MAMP?¿Ya funcionaba antes?

Comment: Hola! pero mamp está bien, funcionaba antes y funciona ahora. Voy a probar pero no creo que sea eso. Gracias igual por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

después de muchos días de dar vuelta cielo y tierra y probar de todo encontré la solución. Felicidad!
Lo publico por si algune está sufriendo como yo pueda resolverlo.

---

Agregar la línea:

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**después** de DB_PASSWORD =

FUNCIONA PARA MAMP ( recordá q tiene contra por defecto y es root )

---

en .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

---

Saludos